# Some results are missing in creating permutation of two numbers that their sum are even

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a strange problem that results are missing when I want to create different permutations of two numbers that the sums of the two numbers are even. I used python 2.6.6.

### My script is:

```
import os
import sys
import math

for i in range(1,39):
    a = -2.2 - 0.2*i
    for j in range(i,39):
        b = -2.2 - 0.2*j
        if (a+b) % 2 == 0:
            print str(a) + " : " +  str(b)
```

---

I thought that this script should give me the desired result. However, I find there are some missing permutation such as -3.4 : -8.6.
I can't find the reason why I have this problem in my script.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are aware of the inherent **imprecisions** of floating point numbers…?

Comment: thank you for your reminder. problem solved

Answer (score 1):

As deceze indicated in a comment, builtin floating point representations cannot precisely represent all decimal numbers, and this can cause some issues (as you just saw).

I would use the decimal module if you need math to work out exactly the way you expect it to.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html